# no output in laravel project when i am adding my style sheet

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5

when i add my `css` file to laravel project it does not work

why this file make laravel project does not work

and when i remove it form the project it work correctly

I put the **css** ,**images** ,and **js** into public folder 
and html into resources folder and use this to require the files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{Request::root()}}/webSite/style.css"/>
```

when i inspect element in browser there is no error

is that correct in css file ?

```css
background-image: url(images/Overlay/1.jpg);
```

Comment: how you added your css please put that code

Comment: what do you mean by does not work. Please specify the issue .

Comment: no output when i run the index page

Comment: ok.. try adding single or double quotes in css property:`background-image: url('images/Overlay/1.jpg');`

Comment: sorry there is no  output

Comment: What laravel version do you use? What is the http response code? Why do you use Request::root() ? Are there any console errors?

Comment: laravel 5.2 -- no there is no console error

Comment: Is the css loaded in page? Is it available in console?

Comment: Try to not use Request::root() try the absolute path or the public path helper method.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('webSite/style.css')}}"/>
```

asset function returns the path of the public folder with parameter path appended